# Calculating number of standard deviations that contain $x$ percent of data

Tags: statistics

I would like to calculate how many standard deviations contain $x\%$ of data in a normal distribution. For example, if I wanted to split my data/normal distribution into thirds, I would need to know how many standard deviations contain $33.3\%$ of my data.

Comment: It's time to do some integrals!

Comment: is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation for this is troublesome, but it is always the same, so usually people consult a table on which it has been precalculated. You should try Google search for “z-score table” or just “standard normal distribution table” and numerous examples will appear.  Or you could use this one, which is the first one I found:

[image: z-score table]

The entry in the row `x.y` and column `0.0z` tells you the probability that a sample element will be no more than `x.yz` standard deviations above the mean.

Looking for $\frac23$ in the table, we find that the entry at row $0.4,$ column $0.03$ is $0.6664$, which is close enough for government work.  This tells us that $\frac23$ of the sample will be less than $0.43$ standard deviations above the mean; therefore $\frac13$ of the sample will be more than $0.43$ standard deviations above the mean, and therefore by symmetry $\frac13$ of the sample will be more than $0.43$ standard deviations below the mean.

So if you want to divide the sample into thirds, the lower third is the part that is up to  $0.43$ standard deviations below the mean; the middle third is the part between $0.43$ standard deviations below and $0.43$ standard deviations above the mean, and the upper third is the part more than  $0.43$ standard deviations above the mean.

Similarly, looking for $\frac34$ in the table we find that it is at about $0.675$ standard deviations, so the quartile cuts are at $-0.675, 0, $ and $+0.675$ standard deviations, respectively.